# What is the fDummy2 field in a device control block (DCB) reserved for?

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am looking through some old C++ serial communications code and noticed that the author has made undocumented use of a 17-bit fDummy2 field inside the [Device Control Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx).  According to every [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx#serial_topic6) I've seen this field is "reserved" but the specs don't clarify what it's reserved for.  So I have two questions:

1. Exactly what is the fDummy2 field reserved for?
2. What is an example use case for manipulating this field against the spec's advice?

Comment: It is an archeological artifact.  What happened to fDummy1?  DCB is stone cold old.  Actually using those bits is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Right, this is an old piece of software that I have no choice but to manage.  I understand that using a reserved field is a bad idea, but the original author must have weighed the usefulness of some feature against the danger of future incompatibility.  My question does not ask if it's dangerous (the spec says it is); it asks for an example of a similar situation in which someone saw the need to use the field in spite of the warning.

Comment: Hmm, no, you are not going to find but the one you found.  There's in general exceedingly little point in showing examples of how *not* do it on a programmers' Q+A site.  If you are unhappy about having to maintain old crappy code then just make it un-crappy.

Comment: The goal is to make it un-crappy. However, Step 1: discover true purpose of crappy code.  Step 2: uncrappify it.  I can't just shrug and gut it.  I appreciate your response but I came here on the chance that one person has seen something similar--not that someone hasn't.

Comment: There is no purpose to it, skip to step 2.

Comment: If I hadn't volunteered that a piece of software in fact uses this field, you'd have still told me that none ever has, and you would have been incorrect.  So I say thank you again, but I cannot logically accept that argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such dummy-fields are added to data-structures "for future need in any extension".

They may be checked for containing the mandatory value to preserve that usefulness, or they may not, in the naive belief that programmers respect and read the documentation.

Thus, using them for your own risks future incompatibility, and might already break your program today.